# Can I make sure my app keeps running after opening a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to open a JFrame that will eventually display values from the code itself but I need the application to continue to run and print things to console after opening the JFrame. At the moment, my application just stops.

Here is my code implementing my JFrame class:

```
public void start(){
    gameWindow window = new gameWindow();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] letterSelect = new char[9];
    List <String> previousGuesses = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    wordMethods methods = new wordMethods();
    methods.randomSelect(letterSelect);
    while(true){
```

etc...
And the code stops as soon as I create the gameWindow object 'window'

Here is my gameWindow class:

```
public class gameWindow extends JFrame{
gameWindow(){
    super("Word Wheel");
    setSize(600,600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}

public void paint(Graphics wheel){
    wheel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    wheel.drawOval(100, 100, 200,200);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new gameWindow().setVisible(true);
    gameWindow w = new gameWindow();
}
```

I have tried changing the default close operation to the different options available as I feel that this is the key to my problem, but I just can't see how to progress.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: @dly The frame already has its "own" thread. The `Event Dispatch Thread`.

Comment: Your question is not clear to provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your app does keep running. The GUI will be kept alive by the `Event Dispatch Thread`, but if your main method ends, one thread will die.

Your first snippet of code is very unclear, you have some random method `start()` and you don't ever seem to even set the frame to be visible.

Your main method in the `gameWindow` class (btw, the name should be `GameWindow`) creates two frames, one which will stay hidden.

If you want good answers, ask a good question. At the moment you're not showing all the relevant code or even showing how you're running your program. Are you running the main method of `gameWindow` or some other class?